# alert() not displayed from Cordova InAppBrowser event listener - Conflict w/ Cordova window.alert hook

Tags: ios, cordova, hook, alert, inappbrowser

Using Cordova CLI version 5.4.1,
Platform is iOS,
Running on iOS emulator

From my app's `onDeviceReady` handler, I am calling a function to set a hook for alerts to be shown using the native dialog as follows:

```
overrideBrowserAlert: function() {
    if (navigator.notification) { // Override default HTML alert with native dialog
        window.alert = function (message) {
            navigator.notification.alert(
                message,    // message
                null,       // callback
                "MyAppTitle", // title
                'OK'        // buttonName
            );
        };
    }
},
```

Most `alert` calls work, but the following doesn't.

At some stage I am opening an `InAppBrowser` window. It closes successfully when the "Done" button is clicked. I have registered an event listener for the event `exit` which does two things:

1. `alert("InAppBrowser window closed");`
2. `Make an AJAX call, get some HTML from a remote server and show it in a <div> element`

HERE IS THE PROBLEM: The AJAX call is successful, but the `alert` IS NOT DISPLAYED. This means the `exit` event is fired successfully and there is a problem with the `alert` call only.

THE PROBLEM GOES AWAY LIKE THIS: Guessing that it might be a scope or event handling conflict, I commented out the code for the `window.alert` hook (i.e. the `overrideBrowserAlert` call above), and sure enough, the alert in the InAppBrowser `exit` event handler works.

**MY QUESTION IS:** Does anyone know how to resolve this conflict so that the alert in the InAppBrowser `exit` event handler works AND the  `window.alert` hook is also enabled?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug on the cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

I've filled an issue
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10855

You can fix it by changing the close method to

```
- (void)close
{
    [CDVUserAgentUtil releaseLock:&_userAgentLockToken];
    self.currentURL = nil;

    __weak CDVInAppBrowserViewController* weakSelf = self;

    // Run later to avoid the "took a long time" log message.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if ([weakSelf respondsToSelector:@selector(presentingViewController)]) {
            [[weakSelf presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
                if ((weakSelf.navigationDelegate != nil) && [weakSelf.navigationDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(browserExit)]) {
                    [weakSelf.navigationDelegate browserExit];
                }
            }];
        } else {
            [[weakSelf parentViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, @jcesarmobile ! This takes care of the problem. I looked at the bug you've opened. Hope you can also submit the proposed solution if you haven't already so that it makes it into an upcoming release.

Comment: Sure, I'll do this weekend. BTW, I fixed another issue on the dialogs plugin that should fix this problem too, install it from github.

Comment: @jcesarmobile any fix for android ? I am stuck from last couple of days